# Subsetting a CSV based on a percentage of unique values

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I've been reading through other similar questions. I have this working, but it is very slow due to the size of the CSV I'm working with. Are there ways to make this more efficient?

My goal:
I have an incredibly large CSV (>100 GB). I would like to take all of the unique values in a column, extract 10% of these, and then use that 10% to subsample the original CSV.

What I'm doing:

1 - I'm pulling all unique values from column 11 and writing those to a text file:

```
cat File1.csv | cut -f11 -d , | sort | uniq > uniqueValues.txt
```

2 - Next, I'm sampling a random 10% of the values in `uniqueValues.txt`:

```
cat uniqueValues.txt | awk 'BEGIN {srand()} !/^$/ { if (rand() <= .10) print $0'} > uniqueValues.10pct.txt
```

3 - Next, I'm pulling the rows in `File1.csv` which have column 11 matching values from `uniqueValues.10pct.txt`:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}($11 in a){print}' uniqueValues.10pct.txt File1.csv > File1_subsample.csv
```

As far as I can tell, this seems to be working. Does this seem reasonable? Any suggestions on how to improve the efficiency?

Comment: If you have [miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) installed, try `mlr --csv -N uniq -g 11 then filter 'urand() <= 0.1' File1.csv > uniqueValues.10pct.txt` to combine the first few steps into one.

Comment: how long does it take to run through all 3 steps? how many values are in `uniqueValues.txt`? do you really need to run `rand()` for each input row or could you perhaps run a single `x=int(rand()*10)` and then just keep the rows where `FNR%10==x`?

Comment: Then `csvgrep -c 11 -f uniqueValues.10pct.txt File1.csv` to do the subsampling if you have csvkit installed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll give those a try.

markp-fuso - To answer you questions. I was testing it on a small set of data. I'm now running it for the first time on a large set. So far it's been a few hours, but I'm not sure the exact full run time yet. The uniqueValues.txt will have between 60,000 and 100,000 values, depending on the data set I'm looking at. I don't know if I need to run rand() the way I've written it. I was cobbling this together from other code I found, but I could try your suggestion as well.

Comment: why can't you directly sample the 11th column from File1.csv in a single pass using awk ? maybe store the sampling decisions along the way so when the same value shows up again then simply apply the pre-made decision instead of sampling it as if new ? is that considered statistically equivalent of an approach ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered to see how to format your input, output, and code as "Code Blocks" and then [edit] your question to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on how to improve the efficiency?

Avoid `sort` in 1st step as 2nd and 3rd do not care about order, you might do your whole 1st step using single awk command as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}!arr[$11]++{print $11}' File1.csv > uniqueValues.txt
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is comma, then for each line I do `arr[$11]++` to get number of occurence of value in 11th column and use `!` to negate it, so `0` becomes true, whilst `1` and greater becomes false. If this hold true I `print` 11th column.

Please test above against your 1st step for you data and then select one which is faster.

As for 3th step you might attemp using not-GNU `AWK` if you are allowed to install tools at your machine. For example author of article¹ [Don’t MAWK AWK – the fastest and most elegant big data munging language!](https://brenocon.com/blog/2009/09/dont-mawk-awk-the-fastest-and-most-elegant-big-data-munging-language/) found `nawk` faster than GNU `AWK` and `mawk` faster than `nawk`. After installing prepare test data and measure times for

```
gawk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}($11 in a){print}' uniqueValues.10pct.txt File1.csv > File1_subsample.csv
nawk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}($11 in a){print}' uniqueValues.10pct.txt File1.csv > File1_subsample.csv
mawk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}($11 in a){print}' uniqueValues.10pct.txt File1.csv > File1_subsample.csv
```

then use one which proved by fastest.

¹be warned that values shown pertains to versions available at September 2009, you might get different times with version available at June 2022.

Comment: As you mentioned, that article you referenced is 13 years old, gawk is far faster now than it was then, and newer versions of mawk have more gawk-like features (e.g. `gensub()`) so I wouldn't expect the same comparative speed results if the same tests were run today. Doing `a[$1]=$0` is wasting memory since you never use the contents of `a[]`, just the indices, so that can just be `a[$1]`. Also, `($11 in a){print}` can be abbreviated to just `$11 in a`.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this to be faster (untested since no sample input/output provided):

```
cut -f11 -d',' File1.csv |
    sort -u > uniqueValues.txt
numUnq=$(wc -l < uniqueValues.txt)
shuf -n "$(( numUnq / 10 ))" uniqueValues.txt |
    awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $11 in vals' - File1.csv
```

You could try replacing that first `cut | sort; numUnq=$(wc...)` with

```
numUnq=$(awk -F',' '!seen[$11]++{print $11 > "uniqueValues.txt"; cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' File1.csv)
```

to see if that's any faster but I doubt it since `cut`, `sort`, and `wc` are all very fast while `awk` has to do regexp-based field splitting and store all `$11` values in memory (which can get slow as the array size increases due to how dynamic array allocation works).

Answer (score 0):

Create a sample *.csv file:

```
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++))
do
    for ((j=1;j<=100;j++))
    do
        echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,${j},k,l,m"
    done
done > large.csv
```

**NOTES:**

- 1,000 total lines
- 100 unique values in the 11th field
- each unique value shows up 10 times in the file

We'll look at a couple `awk` ideas that:

- keep track of unique values as we find them
- apply the random percentage check as we encounter a new (unique) value
- require just a single pass through the source file
- **NOTE:** both of these `awk` scripts (below) replace all of OP's current code (`cat/cut/sort/uniq/cat/awk/awk`)

First idea applies our random percentage check each time we find a new unique value:

```
awk -F',' '
BEGIN        { srand() }
!seen[$11]++ { if (rand() <= 0.10)              # if this is the 1st time we have seen this value and rand() is <= 10% then ...
                  keep[$11]                     # add the value to our keep[] array
             }
$11 in keep                                     # print current line if $11 is an index in the keep[] array
' large.csv > small.csv
```

**NOTES:**

- one drawback to this approach is that the total number of unique values is not *guaranteed* to always be exactly 10% since we're at the mercy of the `rand()` function, for example ...
- a half dozen sample runs generated 70, 110, 100, 140, 110 lines (ie, 7, 11, 10, 14 and 11 unique values) in `small.csv`

A different approach where we pre-generate a random set of `modulo 100` values (ie, `0` to `99`); as we find a new uniq value we check the count (of uniq values) `modulo 100` and if we find a match to our pre-generated set then we print the row:

```
awk -F',' -v pct=10 '
BEGIN        { srand()
               delete mods                      # force awk to treat all "mods" references as an array and not a scalar
               while (length(mods) < pct)       # repeat loop until we have "pct" unique indices in the mods[] array
                     mods[int(rand() * 100)]    # generate random integers betwen 0 and 99
             }
!seen[$11]++ { if ((++uniqcnt % 100) in mods)   # if this is the 1st time we have seen this value then increment our unique value counter and if "modulo 100" is an index in the mods[] array then ...
                  keep[$11]                     # add the value to our keep[] array
             }
$11 in keep                                     # print current line if $11 is an index in the keep[] array
' large.csv > small.csv
```

**NOTES:**

- for a large `pct` this assumes the `rand()` results are evenly distributed between 0 and 1 so that the `mods[]` array is populated in a timely manner
- this has the benefit of printing lines that represent exactly 10% of the possible unique values (depending on number of unique values the percentage will actually be 10% +/- 1%)
- a half dozen sample runs all generated exactly 100 lines (ie, 10 unique values) in `small.csv`

---

If OP still needs to generate the two intermediate (sorted) files (`uniqueValues.txt` and `uniqueValues.10pct.txt`) then this could be done in the same `awk` script via an `END {...}` block, eg:

```
END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"          # this line of code requires GNU awk otherwise OP can sort the files at the OS/bash level
      for (i in seen)
          print i > "uniqueValues.txt"
      for (i in keep)
          print i > "uniqueValues.10pct.txt"        # use with 1st awk script
        # print i > "uniqueValues." pct "pct.txt"   # use with 2nd awk script
    }
```